# ASSIMP bulid error : "invalid option -f"

Tags: c++, assimp

This is my first question here, and i'm not good at english, so be merciful :D
I am trying to build an ASSIMP library in Code::Blocks (MinGW compiler). I used CMake to generate C::B project (i haven't changed much apart from setting DirectX path and enabling BOOST workaround ).When i'm trying to build the project the library seems to build:

> Build finished: 1 errors, 204 warnings (17 minutes, 25 seconds)

but i get an error :

> === Assimp, all ===
>
> ... (warnings)
>
> invalid option -f

Enyone knows what seems to be the problem ?

Comment: could you maybe extract the compiler flags which C::B is passing to mingw? apparently there is a typo in there somewhere

Comment: How do i do that ? I am kind of newbie when it comes to all this make/build and compiler related stuff :(

Comment: I don't use code blocks myself, so I can only give sketchy advice - try right clicking your project in the project explorer and select properties - then a new window should open and somewhere in there you should be able to find "Build Options" which should contain all kind of compiler flags.

Comment: I think the output console should display the exact compiler invocation as well (after `Assimp, all` but before the warnings)